# Problems with icons / Linux Mint 18.2 “Sonya”

Tags: linux-mint, icons

Obviously, I can't move my icons that I have at my home screen. I remember when I ran the Live Session User before I installed Linux Mint, and then everything went perfectly fine. But now after all the settings and so, I must have changed a setting that causes the icons to lock themselfes.

Anyone know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bug in Linux 18.2

```
Menu> System Settings> Desktop>
"Show desktop icons in all monitors"
Close
```

Now right click empty part of screen

```
Desktop
Turn off auto arrange
Turn off align to grid
```

*your icons are free to move*

Comment: Did you caps-lock key get stuck while typing?

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to auto-arranging for some reason.  Right click on the desktop -> "Desktop" -> "Auto-Arrange"

For complete freedom also turn off the "Align to Grid" option.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find the way to revert to the previous mode [Customized Desktop icon sizing in LM 18.2](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=248715):

> Install dconf-editor, run it, in left column go to path org > nemo > desktop and untick the option "use-desktop-grid". Here you are. Desktop behaviour is just like before 18.2 and you can freely resize icons.